# how to create a HTTPserver / HTTPClient

Tags: web-services

I want to understand what kind of server responds to my HTTPClient? is this an ordinary apache HTTP server?

I need to know how i can submit POST via URL form, similar to

`http://myserver/post?message=text&submit=send`

can you give me some pointers on what to study?

this is a sample C++ HTTPClient code for a micro-controller

```
HTTPMap map;
HTTPText inText(str, 512);
map.put("Hello", "World");
map.put("test", "1234");
printf("\nTrying to post data...\n");
ret = http.post("http://httpbin.org/post", map, &inText);
if (!ret)
{
  printf("Executed POST successfully - read %d characters\n", strlen(str));
  printf("Result: %s\n", str);
}
else
{
  printf("Error - ret = %d - HTTP return code = %d\n", ret, http.getHTTPResponseCode());
}
```

And this is the result it returns

```
Trying to post data...
Executed POST successfully - read 344 characters
Result: {
"headers": {
"Content-Length": "21",
"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
"Host": "httpbin.org",
"Connection": "close"
  },
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/post",
  "data": "",
  "origin": "<//my IP>",
  "args": {},
  "form": {
    "Hello": "World",
    "test": "1234"
  },
  "json": null,
  "files": {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be any HTTP server (web server). You can build a stand-alone HTTPServer using any .NET language, but also by writing an ISAPI plugin for ISS, or by installing PHP.

In fact, a normal web server could also be a web service. The difference usually is that a web server serves web pages, while a service serves specialized chunks of information, often not in HTML, but rather in JSON or another format that is more friendly for further processing.

It's mainly a symantic difference, technically there is virtually no difference.